# Two alternate hierarchies SQL BI Datawarehouse

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, hierarchical-data

Could you please advice how can I implement this kind of hierarchy in SQL?

[image]

As you can see there is a multiple-parent hierarchy . It is an alternate hierarchy based on the business requirements where an account can have many parents. Ex: Chemical Revenue has Product Revenue and Chemical Contribution as parents.

Comment: Please add all details in the question. Links tend to fail.

Comment: Here is an [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25644784/3630826) you could reference.

Comment: Is it ok to create two separate hierarchies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by implementing the solution posted hier :
http://www.bi4all.pt/node/136