# How to compare two columns values in mysql,Laravel loop and find the corresponding value in third column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, laravel

### laravel mySQL

I wanna loop through the table two columns and  find the corresponding value in third column when the second input is found?
[This is the image of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BM3UY.jpg)
Jack is first input
laura is second input
loop have to start from jack and find the value from Relation column when it's found the laura(second input)

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: why don't you add another record as ('jack','laura','sister') ?

Comment: $input_1 = $request->input('relation_name');
 $input_2 = $request->input('relation_name2');                       $result=username::select('relationship_name')->where($input_2,'user_name')->get(); return $result; but I'm alway ended with error column not found

Comment: actually, one can mention one relation only..I have to find one user relationship with other users

Comment: @PiruthiviRaj do you have relations such as aunt , uncle , grand father .... or is it just family relations ?

Comment: @cchajar  i have all relations. Paternal uncle, Paternal aunt,Paternal Granfa,Mom,etc. Family as well Relatives

Comment: is there any way to do recursive query in mysql or using laravel?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542013/symbol-a-solution-for-recursive-select-query-in-mysql