# Recursive foreign key in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have the table tbl_relations with columns

```
id,user_name,relation_name,relation_name_id
```

[image: tbl_relations table]

relation_name_id is the foreign key referencing id in the same table.
In laravel I will select two inputs from id and    need to get the collections of data from input one to  till it's reach the second input using foreign key recursive method..is it possible?

This way I need to get the collection

[image]

Comment: You will have to need to use MySQL's 8 CTE and recursive queries that is your best option with this data model.

Comment: @RaymondNijland will you please convert this into laravel     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542013/symbol-a-solution-for-recursive-select-query-in-mysql

Answer (score 2):

This solution is probably inefficient but it will work:

```
class Relation extends Model {
     protected $table = 'tbl_relations';
     protected $with = [ 'related' ];

     public function related() {
          return $this->hasOne(Relation::class, 'relation_name_id'); 
     }
}
```

Each time the `Relation` model is loaded it should trigger a loading of the `related` relation.

You can then do:

```
Relation::find(1)->related->related->id;
```

Note this solution does not take into account specific MySQL optimizations so will probably be the slowest possible solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot but   "Trying to get property 'related' of non-object
" getting this error brother

Comment: I think it's to do with the direction. The idea is `Relation` **has** another relation meaning there's some relation where its `relation_name_id` is the id of this relation. In my example I used `1` as the ID but based on what you shared that probably won't work, however `Realtion::find(2)->relation->id` will probably return `1`