# fetching table data with single query

Tags: mysql

I want to access all data under name='vehicle'  so all child's and sub child's should get in single query

[image]

I have tried this query

```
SELECT a.CID as MainCategoryID, b.CID as ChildCategoryID, b.parentID
FROM categories a, categories b
WHERE a.CID = b.parentID AND NAME='vehicle'
```

Comment: and what you have tried post your query

Comment: How deep your categories can be (how many subchilds ?) ? Have a look at this article : http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: try have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513418/how-to-do-the-recursive-select-query-in-mysql

Comment: @AlexandreN. there can be n-level sub categories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution should be the following:

```
SELECT @pv:=cid AS 'cid', name, parentID FROM categories
JOIN (SELECT @pv:=0) tmp
WHERE parentID = @pv
```

you can find a SQLFiddle here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c75a0/6

Comment: actually, I don't know much about variables in MYSQL, I just took inspiration from here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513418/how-to-do-the-recursive-select-query-in-mysql) and did the necessary adaptations. It was a bit of an experiment of learn by doing

Comment: thanks for the query.but i am  facing another problem when sub categories are not in sequence.  CREATE TABLE categories (
  cid INT,
  name VARCHAR(30),
  parentID INT
);

INSERT INTO categories (cid, name, parentID) 
VALUES (1, 'vehicles', 0), (2, 'two wheelers', 0), (3, 'two wheelers with gear',1), (4, 'moped',1); here is changed schema for your SQL fiddle with same query i get output as only first subcategory and rest are ignored. Can you help with that?

Comment: I think that the approach I proposed doesn't work in this case. In the link in my previous post you can find an alternative solution

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.CID as MainCategoryID, b.CID as ChildCategoryID, b.parentID
FROM categories a
LEFT JOIN categories b ON a.CID = b.parentID
WHERE a.NAME = 'vehicle'
ORDER By a.CID
```

Comment: i want query like select .......where name='vehicle' then it should display all record and sub records upto n level under vehicles

Comment: you need to use join for every single sub-category level

Comment: but if levels are dynamic then how should i handle query?

Comment: It does not work like that. You cant join your mainCategory table with dynamic tables. you need to clarify the joining fields and stuff!