# Database for manage countries, states and cities

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to manage countries, states/province and cities name information. All information will display on webpage with drop down list or other ways. Currently I am designing my database. I have two ideas to design tables

**1. use only one table**

countries, states/provinces and cities are usually very stable information, so I want to use only one table to manage all information and make it reference to itself such as:

> ```
> id  name           parent_id type
> --+--------------+----------+--
> 1   USA            null      1
> 2   California     1         2
> 3   Los Angeles    2         3
> 4   San Francisco  2         3
> ```

type: 1 for country, 2 for states or provinces and 3 for cities

**2. use separate tables**

I will use one table to manage country, and one table to manage states/province and one table to manage cities. then make them reference between each other.

So which one is better? and please explain your reason.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think "speed" is the problem here, like @fanfan1609 said, but if you use one table, you would save "different" things in one table. A state is not a country and so on.
Think of database-normalization.

What if a city will get a postalcode, because you need it? Would you change your monster-table to have a postalcode column, just for one type? Then you begin to add a "meta" column of type varchar, and let the crap begin.

Answer (score 0):

I think #2 is better.

With separate tables, you can easily manage records.
For SELECT query; it's is faster

Example
If you want select country only ,

1# : 
SELECT * FROM countries WHERE type = 1 ;

2# : 
SELECT * FROM countries;

Of course; 2# is faster because data in tables is less than 1#

Comment: but what will be happen if I try select all cities in California?

Comment: Assume you have these tables as countries, cities, provinces.
Your sql may be 

`SELECT * 
 FROM cities AS c JOIN provinces as p on p.id = c.province_id 
 WHERE p.name = "California";`

Answer (score 0):

You should certainly choose table-splitted solution. It is so due extensibility issue. Once you need to extend your country or state dataset stored, you'll see how inefficient it would be.

Answer (score -2):

#1 is Better than #2

also, you can create recursive view 
Take a look here: 
[How to do the Recursive SELECT query in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513418/how-to-do-the-recursive-select-query-in-mysql)

Good Luck !