# MYSQL SELECT LOOP dynamically

Tags: mysql, loops, subquery

I'm a newbie in mysql and not sure if possible to have a loop statement in select.

My Table:

```
ID      user_id     parent
1       13          2
2       14          2
3       15          13
4       16          13
5       17          14
6       18          14
7       19          15
8       20          15
```

parent with value of 2 has no parent. it is something like root
`user_id` is equivalent to child

so if i do

SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE parent = 2

basically output is:

```
ID      user_id     parent
1       13          2
2       14          2
```

is there a way i can get the other child? should i do subquery? If 2 is selected this is the image i want to achieve: http://awesomescreenshot.com/04b2y7qfe2

Comment: What is the other child? What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: If `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE parent = 2` it will get all the table entries, parent col will connect to user_id. something like this [link](http://awesomescreenshot.com/04b2y7qfe2)

Comment: You want to do a recursive select? See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513418/how-to-do-the-recursive-select-query-in-mysql) for details. In your case, your `parent` column would be `col1` and your `user_id` column would be `col3`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can connect your parents users with their children users:

This will display only record that have parents:

```
SELECT c.user_id, c.parent, p.user_id, p.parent
FROM my_table c, my_table p
WHERE c.parent = p.user_id
```

Or using left Join, display records that have or have no parents (the ones with 2 as parentID)

```
SELECT c.user_id as ChildID, c.parent as ChildParentID, p.user_id as ParentID, p.parent as ParentOfParentID
FROM my_table c
LEFT JOIN my_table p
ON c.parent = p.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like what is often called an adjacency tree list, where a tree structure is defined in list form by specifying IDs and parent IDs, with a given parent ID value indicating the root node of the tree (in this case, the value `2`).

Amir's answer will give you the immediate children of each node. If you'd like to retrieve entire branches of the tree, from a given node, you could look at [Modified Preorder Tree Traversal (MPTT)](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/). You just fetch all rows where the `left` field value falls between the root node's `left` and `right` values. The key drawback with this method is that on average 50% of the records in the table need to be updated when adding or removing nodes from the tree. If you've got a big table, that can be a bit of a performance hit.

Unfortunately, as far as I know, MySQL doesn't have a way of performing recursive queries, which would be another way of solving this problem. Some other database systems of this functionality, but not MySQL.