# How to get MBR of lineString column including multiple rows?

Tags: mysql, spatial

I need to get MBR from table with multiple rows from `lineString` type column.

Using [envelope](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/gis-general-property-functions.html#function_envelope) I could get MBR from single row because `envelope` is not aggregate function.

How to get one MBR of lineString column including multiple rows?

Comment: Well, an option may be: find points for `LineString`: first and second- so, for all rows. Then, select minimum X, Y and maximum X, Y and build MBR explicitly as Polygon from there. Will work, of course, if your `lineStrings` are just point-to-point lines (so, contain only two points - otherwise it's impossible to predict all points from a line). Alternative may be stored code which iterates through cursor. But that would be slow. That's the place, where spatial fails (that's why using it in general is debatable - either it's a good practice or bad)

Comment: @AlmaDo , I have done it. But you are right. It's better to calculate result else somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complicated query. Last row would has result.

```
SELECT 
   @id := id, 
   @geometry := Envelope(if(isNull(@geometry), `line`, GeometryCollection( `line` , geomFromText(AsText(@geometry))))), 
   AsText(@geometry)
FROM `table_line`
JOIN (SELECT @id :=0, @geometry := NULL) `tmp`
WHERE id > @id
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16513418/1503018)

`geomFromText(AsText(@geometry))` -- this is necessary because GeometryCollection does not work with direct variables.

P.S. but it's very complicated, do not use it in production.