# mysql: select from a table where key is equal to a value and also select all the rows related to that value directly or indirectly

Tags: php, mysql

The scenario is this

```
key    |    value   |  sponsor_id
===================================
1      |    mykel   |  0
2      |    sydney  |  1 
3      |    darren  |  2
4      |    luis    |  3
```

What I want to achieve is something like this

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE sponsor_id = 0;
```

So basically, "mykel" field is the on that will be selected. But, I also want to select all the child element of sponsor_id 0;

As stated in the table

- 1 is connected to 0
- 2 is connected to 1
- 3 is connected to 2

In conclusion, I want to select rows starting from the parent index which is 0 and also all the child rows connected to it wether directly or indirectly.

Is it achievable using one straight query?

Comment: Yes, I believe you'll have to use at least one AND in your WHERE clause...is there a simple linear relationship between sponsor_id and key or is it more random?

Comment: No, there's no relationship between the key and sponsor_id. the key is more just like a autoincrement field for that table. the sponsor_id is a foregin_key let's say from another table.

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand your data relationships.  It sounds like a simple join, but I suspect I'm missing something in your question.  Are you familiar with joins and sub queries?

Comment: Edit: sorry. the sponsor_id is from the key itself.

Comment: You are asking for a recursive or hierarchical query.  MySQL provides basically no support for this.  You can do it in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Found this answer that might be helpful to you:

[How to do the Recursive SELECT query in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513418/how-to-do-the-recursive-select-query-in-mysql)

```
select col1, col2, @pv:=col3 as 'col3' from table1
join
(select @pv:=1)tmp
where col1=@pv
```

SQL FIDDLE:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9635d2/1

```
| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 |
----------------------
|    1 |    a |    5 |
|    5 |    d |    3 |
|    3 |    k |    7 |
```