# Recursive select in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with following format

```
TaskID  ParentTaskID
1       1
2       1
3       2
4       2
5       2
10      10
11      11
12      11
13      0
14      14
```

I want the result as below,if taskid is 1

```
TaskID
1
2
3
4
5
```

if its 2 then

```
Taskid
2
3
4
5
```

if its 10 then 10

means I want to select rows having taskid =1 with rows having parenttaskid=1
with rows having parenttaskid in above selection & so on........

please use this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9db0c3/6

Comment: select t2.id,t2.parenttaskid from tbl_taskmaster t1 Inner join tbl_taskmaster t2
on t1.id=t2.parenttaskid where t1.parenttaskid=1

Comment: update your question with what's in your comment.

Comment: do you require an answer that is a sql statement, or would a stored procedure meet your needs? Is there a safe assumption about the max number of levels of recursion one would ever find?

Comment: MySQL does not support recursive select is a short answer. but you should be able to get what you need using sub queries check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513418/how-to-do-the-recursive-select-query-in-mysql

Comment: @RobP I need sql statement.Thereis no any max limit

Comment: I think you have a logic issue in your question. If taskid = 2 then task_id = 1 should be included in the result. the parent of task_id= 2 is 1

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does not support recursive select.

But, the query below should do trick that you are looking for

```
SELECT t.TaskID
FROM task AS t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT a.TaskID 
    FROM task AS a
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT TaskID 
        FROM task
        WHERE TaskID = 11 OR ParentTaskID = 11
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ParentTaskID
        FROM task
        WHERE TaskID = 11 OR ParentTaskID = 11
    ) AS s ON s.TaskID = a.ParentTaskID
) AS s ON s.TaskID = t.TaskID
```

Comment: i was tried your query bt its not getting the exact result http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9db0c3/6

Comment: I just updated the answer. I think you have a logic issue in your question. If the taskid = 2 then the output should also be 1 2 3 4 5 the parent of task_id = 2 is 1 so 1 should be included http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9db0c3/15

Comment: if taskid=2, then it means i want to select rows having taskid =2 & also the rows having parenttaskid =2 & if any child tasks having parenttaskid from above resultset. i hope u got the logic...

Comment: Actually my requirement is to delete tasks related to given taskid, and further child tasks having parenttaskid as given taskid.

Comment: @Haris you can try to set cascade delete on foreign key if your requirement is for delete only

Comment: I suggest you take my query and play around with it. :)

Answer (score 1):

As Mike already said, MySQL does not support recursive select or recursive functions.

If you have a maximum logical limit on your task concatination (like 5) you can use hard coded self joins.

```
SELECT
t1.taskid as taskid1,
t2.taskid as taskid2,
t3.taskid as taskid3,
t4.taskid as taskid4,
t5.taskid as taskid5
FROM task t1
LEFT JOIN task t2 ON t2.parenttaskid = t1.taskid
LEFT JOIN task t3 ON t3.parenttaskid = t2.taskid
LEFT JOIN task t4 ON t4.parenttaskid = t3.taskid
LEFT JOIN task t5 ON t5.parenttaskid = t4.taskid
```

Which will produce this result: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9f80/1/0

By the way you have some self referencing tasks in your input data which would produce an infinity loop with recursion.