# Select until in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, do-while

I have this table the contains `user_id` and `father_id`.
I want to select all the `father_id`s that are associated with the `user_id` until the value of the `father_id = 0` and store them in a comma-separated format.

Table: `network`

```
select user_id, father_id from network where user_id = 1762;
```

```
user_id father_id
1762    1761
```

```
select user_id, father_id from network where user_id = 1761; -- resulting father_id from the first query
```

```
user_id father_id
1761    1760
```

```
select user_id, father_id from network where user_id = 1760; -- resulting father_id from the second query
```

```
user_id father_id
1760    0
```

In this example, I want to get all the `father_id`s until i reached `father_id = 0` by using the resulting `father_id` as the `next user_id`.

Comment: What version of MySQL? In MySQL 8.0 you can do this using a single SQL. In MySQL 5.x you need multiple ones.

Comment: I'm using MySQL 5.5. I will try to update to version 8.0 if it is simpler.

Comment: A workaround is to use a variable.

Comment: Sorry for asking too much, I'm just new to this. A little bit of head start will be a great help. Thanks!

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28252370/selecting-hierarchical-data-using-mysql-variable

Comment: Update to MySQL 8+.  You are storing hierarchical data and earlier versions of MySQL have basically no support for such data.