# Get all indirect parents of a child

Tags: mysql, sql

i would like to know how can i get all indirect parents of a child in a MySQL database.

My tabel looks like:

```
 uid | referral_uid | created
 9   | 8            | <timestamp>
 10  | 9            | <timestamp>
 11  | 9            | <timestamp>
 12  | 10           | <timestamp>
```

So for example for uid=12 i would like to get the indirect referral_uids which are 8 and 9.
For uid=11 the indirect parent would be only 8.

Can this be achieved in one sql query? Thank you

I have tried the following http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d30b4/8 using the mentioned link for recursive query. I am doing something wrong but i can't really figure it out what.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do the Recursive SELECT query in Mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513418/how-to-do-the-recursive-select-query-in-mysql)

Comment: I have tried this but it doesnt seem to work, and i'm not sure what im doing wrong. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d30b4/8

Comment: Accepted answer assumes that table is ordered by `col1`. Check out [the second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24901882/451518). It seems to work for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d30b4/10

Comment: Check this out: http://guilhembichot.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/with-recursive-and-mysql.html