# Recursive query with MySQL

Tags: mysql, graph-databases, recursive-query

Let's consider 2 tables with a "tree" table having `id` as primary key.
And a "link" table having (`src_id`, `dst_id`) as primary key, and those foreign keys:

- `src_id` (referencing the `tree` table)
- `dst_id` (also referencing the `tree` table)

How can we select all the sources of the sources of the sources a particular tree (without going crazy)?

Edit:

```
SQL> DESC tree;
+---------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id      | int(11)       | NO   | PRI |         |       |
+---------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SQL> DESC link;
+---------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| src_id  | int(11)       | NO   | FK  |         |       |
| dst_id  | int(11)       | NO   | FK  |         |       |
+---------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do the Recursive SELECT query in Mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513418/how-to-do-the-recursive-select-query-in-mysql)

Comment: [Rendering Trees with Closure Tables](http://karwin.blogspot.com/2010/03/rendering-trees-with-closure-tables.html)

Comment: Thanks for the links. Yes there's pretty much the same wanted-feature. However my question is specific because over 2 tables.