# Get column values as rows, recursively from a hierarchy in database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that returns me this:

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| L_1_teacher | L_1_student | L_2_teacher | L_2_student |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|      333333 |       33667 |      111111 |       33668 |
|      222222 |       33667 |      111111 |       33669 |
|      222222 |       33667 |      111111 |       33670 |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I need to "union" the two teacher columns. The expected output is:

```
+-------------+
|    teachers |
+-------------+
|      333333 |
|      222222 |
|      111111 |
+-------------+
```

Since it's a long query, I cannot afford to run it twice (actually, I have more than two levels of teachers), select teachers on every level and union them.

**What I tried:** I stored the results of this query into a temp table `tree` and did:

```
SELECT L_1_teacher as "teachers" FROM tree
UNION
SELECT L_2_teacher as "teachers" FROM tree
```

but it threw me an error saying `Error Code: 1137. Can't reopen table: 'tree'` (MySQL prohibits using the same temporary table twice in the query)

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: This is called a PIVOT query.  Unfortunately, mysql does not have a native solution for pivoting.  There are however [many examples](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+pivot) of pivot style queries in mysql.  The union that you mention is one of them.

Comment: @paqogomez Thanks for the pointer. I checked the link out. There's a haystack of questions. I was wondering if you could suggest a solution here, if that wouldn't be too much to ask for :)
This is kinda urgent. Hence the request.

Comment: Please provide sample data of the original table.

Comment: Happy to help, but as @AbhikChakraborty suggests, we need a bit more info.  Could you put together a sample [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com)? Or let us understand what about this query is so intensive?

Comment: I'm creating a fiddle. Thanks for your patience :)

Comment: @paqogomez, AbhikChakraborty Here's a fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5c3cb/2

Comment: I think what you have here is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)  You've asked about how to pivot this query, when your real question should be about how to do [recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24901882/2589202) or [parent child queries](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) in mysql.

Comment: @paqogomez Changed the title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I confirm your tought, you can't refer twice in the same query to a temporary table. This is already documented in [MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/temporary-table-problems.html).

An alternative would be to create another temporary table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tree2 LIKE tree;
INSERT INTO tree2 select * from tree;

SELECT L_1_teacher as "teachers" FROM tree
UNION
SELECT L_2_teacher as "teachers" FROM tree2
```

Comment: I thought about this. But did not seem like an elegant solution.

Comment: I'm curious why a downvote... @th3an0maly Unfortunately it seems like it is the only solution, with MySQL.

Comment: I was the downvoter and perhaps its too harsh.  You have answered the question as it was asked.  However, I think this is going to be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  We just dont have enough information to give a good answer.

Comment: @paqogomez I also think this seems to be an XY problem like most of the temporary table related question. However, creating another table is AFAIK the only solution if really you can't avoid the usage of union on the tmp table. In any ways, thanks for removing the downvote.

Comment: As i suspected, its not a pivot or a temp table problem, its a tree problem.