# mysql query for children and grandchildren

Tags: javascript, mysql

column view

```
+-----------------------+
| name                  |
+-----------------------+
| ELECTRONICS           |
|  TELEVISIONS          |
|   TUBE                |
|   LCD                 |
|   PLASMA              |
|  GAME CONSOLES        |
|  PORTABLE ELECTRONICS |
|   MP3 PLAYERS         |
|    FLASH              |
|   CD PLAYERS          |
|   2 WAY RADIOS        |
|    FRS                |
+-----------------------+
```

table core.category

```
Id      ParentId   Name

1       null       ELECTRONICS
2       1          TELEVISIONS
3       2          TUBE
4       2          LCD
5       2          PLASMA
6       1          GAME CONSOLES
7       1          PORTABLE ELECTRONICS
8       7          MP3 PLAYERS
9       8          FLASH
10      7          CD PLAYERS
11      1          2 WAY RADIOS
12      11         FRS
```

If I SELECT 1,

result is (shows children and grandchildren) expect that there is more than 1 grandparent(ELECTRONICS)

```
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
| 1   |
| 2   |
| 3   |
| 4   |
| 5   |
| 6   |
| 7   |
| 8   |
| 9   |
| 10  |
| 11  |
| 12  |
+-----+
```

If I select 2

result must be

```
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
| 2   |
| 3   |
| 4   |
| 5   |
+-----+
```

i got this for selected category and his children ( need more to output grandchildren)

```
module.exports.categorySearch = function(searchCategory, cb) {
  var query = 'SELECT category_id \
   FROM core.category AS c \
   WHERE category_id = $1::integer
UNION
   SELECT category_id \
   FROM core.category AS c \
   WHERE category_ParentId = $1::integer
;';
  var map = function(err, result) {
     if(err) {
        return cb(err, null);
      }
      var list = [];
      result.rows.forEach(function(row, i) {
        list.push(new Category(row));
      });
      cb(null, list);
    };
  repository.queryDb(query, [searchCategory], map);
};
```

result is

```
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
| 1   |
| 2   |
| 6   |
| 7   |
| 11  |
+-----+
```

what should i add to my select statement

Comment: is this in a node server...if not what does javascript have to do with it?

Comment: Also in addition to this: do you only want to go 2 steps or through ALL steps? (that means if there are then also grand grand parents,....) ?

Comment: i want to show all under the selected category, including the selected category

Comment: That would mean then that you want to have a recursive result of the category and all that is under it (the question title is a bit misleading there). Additionally as some mentioned do you use just mysql or also javascript (as you used the tag there). and if javascript: What code do you have so far there and what frameworks (if any like jquery, angularjs,...) are you using for javascript? These would all be important informations there.

Comment: Do you want `category and its subcategories only` OR `category with subcategory and sub-subcategory and so on`

Comment: category with sub and so on, then im using angularjs

Comment: do you have any code written so far? (aka what statements do you have so far for getting the data from the database? (not sure what options angular gives as I never used it myself so far, but that info would also be helpful). and if you want to use angular for this you should add angularjs (if it exists as tag) to the tags.

Comment: i just want to improve my select statement so i can get the children and grandchildren and so on, recursive i think

Comment: so something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513418/how-to-do-the-recursive-select-query-in-mysql

Comment: cant understand that wait ill have new update, i can output , children now but not grand children and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH RECURSIVE categorytree AS (
  SELECT c.category_id, 0 as depth
  FROM core.category AS c
  WHERE c.category_id = $1::integer

  UNION ALL

  SELECT c.category_id, t.depth + 1 as depth
  FROM core.category AS c
  INNER JOIN categorytree t
    ON t.category_id = c.category_ParentId
)

SELECT category_id FROM categorytree
```

shows the selected and children and grandchildren and so on...

```
+-----+
| id  |
+-----+
| 1   |
| 2   |
| 3   |
| 4   |
| 5   |
| 6   |
| 7   |
| 8   |
| 9   |
| 10  |
| 11  |
| 12  |
+-----+
```