# SQL - Recursive delete in one query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

Assuming I have a DB like this:

- Folders (with "parent folder" column)
- Files (with "folder" column)

Is there a way to delete all files in a folder that has sub folders in only one query?

Example:

- Folders:

  - id,name,parent
  - 1, folder1, 0
  - 2, folder2, 1
  - 3, folder3, 2
- Files:

  - name, folder
  - file1, 2

And I try to delete folder1. That single query should delete all files in folder2, and folder3 becasue folder2 is under folder1, and folder2 is under folder1.

** I know I can do this as a recursive script, but I want to educate myself more

Comment: Foreign key, on delete cascade?

Comment: @jarlh Sound good. have you try it? Or is just a guess?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I had done similar, multiple times in the past. Depending on your needs, a cascade delete is perfect for this.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, just a guess, hence the question mark.

Comment: @Phill looks like doesnt work in SQL Sever 2014 http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e6d84/1  Says: `may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.`

Comment: @Amit do you mean recursive query? because that is the way you can solve this question.

Comment: The "delete cascade" sounds realy good for this, Im reading about it and I think that can work. My curiosity has reached satisfaction :)

Thanks for all of you helpers!

Comment: @Amit I already try on SQL Server 2014 and doesnt seem to work. What is your db version? Also you mean recursive script or recursive query?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I ment I know I can just write a PHP code that does that, but I want it to be pure SQL. This is an academic question, and not an acctual one that I encountered now or in the past. I usually run XAMPP for my enviorment. (Mysql).

Comment: @amit check this example http://stackoverflow.com/a/21378603/3470178

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza i donno what sqlfiddle is but it works on my local version of sql server 2014.

Comment: @Phill You mean my fiddle or you create your own?

Comment: I'm running sql server on my computer, it works fine. I don't know what sql fiddle is, never seen it before.

Comment: @Phil sqlfiddle is a site where you can create a test database, from mysql to postgres or oracle. You can see the schema i try here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e6d84/1

Comment: SQLFIDDLE is not working for me. "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT".
The solution of delete cascade is good, but is there a way not only to delete folder3, but also to delete the files in it? that is my main problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @jarlh, a really nice solution is having a Foreign key, with on delete cascade.

Comment: This totally works, IFF you don't need to do any of your own bookkeeping DURING the cascaded delete.  Since it now becomes a "db-managed recursive action", the only way to affect it's behavior is usually something like triggers, which a lot of times is less than an optimal solution. But it you don't have this requirement, this answer works, and it works quite well.