# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version while declaring a variable

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have been searching for this solution all over the internet and I haven't been able to find the solution for this:

I am trying to get the following code to run:

```
BEGIN             
    DECLARE @var int             
    SELECT @var =5
    WHILE @var > 0    
    PRINT replicate('* ', @var)     
    SET @var = @var - 1             
    END
```

I have been trying to run this query, and I am getting the following message:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @var int SELECT @var = 5
```

WHILE @var > 0  ' at line 1

I know that there have been iterated many times, but the solution discussed in other conversations have not been working on my console.

Comment: What is `SELECT ... WHILE`? I [don't think that's a thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34790941/mysql-while-in-select-clause).

Comment: you have many errors in your script the most grave is PRINT replicate mysql doesn't have both, maybe this is for anaother rdms

Answer (score 1):

Your code is actually sql server, which doesn't work in mysql

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `ABC`(
IN _tablename VARCHAR(50) -- is a parameter in which table       
                            --    name is stored
)
BEGIN
             
    SET @var = 5;             
    WHILE @var > 0  DO
    select repeat('* ', @var);
    SET @var = @var - 1;             
    END  WHILE;
End$$
DELIMITER ;
```

To give you a better understanding.

This procedure return 5 Recordset, depending on which programing language you use, such multi queries may not be supprted. In workbench you see them, when you run `CALL testdb1.ABC('test');

Comment: Perhaps how do I print this?

Comment: Also, while running this query on hackerrank,I got the following error:

Comment: ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 5: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER or SET_USER_ID privilege(s) for this operation

Comment: check please the DEFINER at the start, eventually your user that has that privilge is called differently. Further what do you wnat to print.?