# SQL: Order by a list of foreign_key numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, tree, foreign-keys, relational-database

A simplified example:

I have a SQL table called `things`. Things by themselves have an `id` and a `name`.  Things are part of a tree, e.g. a thing can have a parent; Exactly how to this is stored is not important, important is however that it is possible to obtain a list of thing ids from the root node to the current thing.

I have another table, called `properties`. A property has a `thing_id` column, a `name` column and a `value` column.

I now want, for the current thing, to obtain all properties, **ordered by thing_id, in order of the paths from root thing to current thing**.

e.g., if the current thing is nested like this: `Root(1) > Vehicle(4) > Car(2) > Hybrid(3)`, I would want the list of properties be returned with the properties that have a `thing_id==1` first, followed by the ones with `thing_id == 4`, then `thing_id==2` and finally `thing_id==3`.

How can this be done using SQL? (without using N+1 selects)

Comment: I am using Rails, and I would like a solution to at least work on both SQLite and MySQL2.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL this can be achieved with use of recursive query. Here is an example

```
DECLARE @item as varchar(10) 

with CTE (main_part, sub_part, NestingLevel) 
as    
( 
                select main_part, sub_part, 1 from tblParts 
                        where main_part = @item 

                union all 

                select tblParts.main_part, tblParts.sub_part, (NestingLevel + 1) from tblParts 
                inner join CTE on tblParts.main_part = CTE.sub_part 
) 

select * from CTE
```

In order to address this in MySQL you can try temporary table approach. Here is a good example of it: [How to do the Recursive SELECT query in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513418/how-to-do-the-recursive-select-query-in-mysql)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, I haven't try it on MySQL, but since both MS SQL and MySQL are RDBMS I think this approach is viable for MySQL as well.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson then you will probably need to go with stored procedure approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513418/how-to-do-the-recursive-select-query-in-mysql

Comment: Could you clarify your answer a little? I have some trouble figuring out what is going on.

Comment: @Qqwy, I checked MySQL docs and found that MySQL does not support WITH command. So it definitely won't work with MySQL. I believe this can solved with temporary table. See revised answer