# MySQL selecting record based on parent

Tags: mysql

I got a table with the user name and their guarantor. I want to select the record based on 1 name and follow by the guarantor and continue search next record based on this guarantor's guarantor.

```
=========================
Name        | ParentName
=========================
Ali         | Abu
Bola        | Ali
Cat         | Bola
Danny       | Cat
Dog         | Elephant
=========================
```

When I put in Danny to the parameter, my expected result will be :

```
=========
Name
=========
Danny
Cat
Bola
Ali
=========
```

Is there any possibility to done it with query?

Comment: you can do with procedure

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it!
You need to create a *recursive* *query* using *functions/procedures*.

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513418/how-to-do-the-recursive-select-query-in-mysql)