# Filter records by project in typo3 database

Tags: sql, typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I have two projects:

**1. ProjectFOO with Root Page UID 85**

**2. ProjectBAR with Root Page UID 1**

[image: Projects]

Both projects include the extension **ke_search**. I need to update the record `pages` from the table `tt_content` where `list_type` is "ke_search_pi1" BUT only from `ProjektFOO`.

This is my sql so far:

```
UPDATE `tt_content` SET `pages` = 42 WHERE `list_type` = ke_search_pi1;
```

**Problem**: This SQL query will set `pages` from every project to 42, instead of selecting only records from `ProjectFOO`.

What do i have to include in my WHERE statement, to only select records from `ProjectFOO` ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no root_pid column in the pages table. So you would need to get the records recursively.

There is a post about selecting records recursively:
[How to do the Recursive SELECT query in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513418/how-to-do-the-recursive-select-query-in-mysql)

This way you can get all UID belonging to ROOT PID 85. After you create the temporary table you can use that one to update your tt_content table.