# Why are there less records returned from MySQL when using a group by clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I recently started work with MySQL using MySQL Workbench. I have a total of 1000 rows in my table. When I run this query I get 1000 rows:

```
SELECT Id, Dname, DeptId
FROM DEPARTMENT;
```

[image]

However, when I add a `GROUP BY` clause I get only 44 rows:

```
SELECT Id, Dname, DeptId
FROM DEPARTMENT
GROUP BY DeptId;
```

[image]

**Why is it happening ?** Is it that MySQL Workbench is truncating the rows while displaying them?

**EDIT:**

When I give this query, it too returns me `44 rows`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(DEPTID) 
FROM DEPARTMENT;
```

[image]

Comment: There may be only 44 unique entries in the DeptId

Answer (score 0):

Probably your table has 44 unique DeptId.

It isn't a bug or whatever in MySQL Workbench. It is how *GROUP BY* works. If you *GROUP BY* by Id (and it is your PK) you will get the 1000 rows.

GROUP BY clause aggregates the data as you can see here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

### EDIT

```
SELECT @pv:=Id AS d_id, Dname, DeptId
FROM DEPARTMENT
JOIN
(SELECT @pv:=1) tmp
WHERE DeptId=@pv
```

In **`@pv:=1`** 1 is the first id in the table.

Tell me if it works. Reference: [How to do the Recursive SELECT query in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513418/how-to-do-the-recursive-select-query-in-mysql)

Comment: Oh ! Then, how can I achieve this
`DeptId` is an optional field. When is it populated, it means it is a sub department of some department. Now I want  "List all sub-departments of departments"

Comment: Ohhh... what you need is a recursive query. I'm gonna edit the answer.

Comment: Above returns only two rows. This query worked --> `select * from DEPARTMENT where DeptId in (select ID from DEPARTMENT where DeptId is not null) `

Comment: Don't you have sub-sub-departments?

Comment: Yes, I have, recursion an be till any level. But I want only till 1st level

Comment: Nice. So, I think you query is getting all departments that has an parent, 1st level or not. Take a look in the last edit.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate DeptId's will not be selected when u are using groupby..your table may contain only 44 unique DeptId's so it is displaying 44 rows

Comment: Oh ! Then, how can I achieve this `DeptId` is an optional field. When is it populated, it means it is a sub department of some department. Now I want "List all sub-departments of departments"

Comment: don't use groupby or distinct

Comment: How about `Count number of sub departments under each department`

Comment: Are u using separate table for department and sub department?

Comment: There is only one table `DEPARTMENT` having fields as `Id` `Dname` and `DeptId`. If `DeptId` is not null, it means that this dept is sub-dept of some department.

Comment: select * from DEPARTMENT where DeptId  in (select ID from DEPARTMENT where DeptId is null);    try this

Comment: No it does not give desired results. It returns same 44 rows

Comment: try this..
 
select ID from DEPARTMENT where DeptId is not null;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121733/discussion-between-simpleguy-and-rinu-antony).

Answer (score 0):

To get the 1st level sub-departments you should use:

```
select *
from DEPARTMENT
where
    DeptId in (select ID from DEPARTMENT where DeptId is null)
```

Comment: `WHERE DeptId IS NOT NULL`

Comment: I think, to get the 1st level, should be NOT NULL to select the parents.