# MySQL iterate through and select related rows using a while loop

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way using only MySQL query to select ID=? and its related children and grandchildren and so on... until there are no more.

Example:

[image]

*ID 1: Has is the parent,
ID 2: Is the child of the parent,
IDs 3-8: Are the grandchildren*

I want to get results such as:

```
if ID=1, select 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
OR ID=2, select 2,3,4,5,6,7,8
OR ID=3, select 3
```

Something like:

```
select from TABLE where id=? while related>0 select from TABLE where related=? end while
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do the Recursive SELECT query in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16513418/how-to-do-the-recursive-select-query-in-mysql)

Comment: You can probably create a function for returning you first level children for a record and call that function recursively.

Comment: If you can change table structure than you should really use [nested sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). There are  many realisations for all popular frameworks: [laravel](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset), [doctrine](https://github.com/blt04/doctrine2-nestedset), [yii2](https://github.com/creocoder/yii2-nested-sets) and others.