# Sql query to find the ancestors of selected file

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 fields namely id,filename and prev_id used for storing uploaded files

```
Id |  filename | prev_id
---------------------------
1  |  file1    | NULL
2  |  file2    | 1
3  |  file3    | 2
4  |  file4    | NULL
5  |  file5    | 4
6  |  file6    | 5
```

file3 is the latest uploaded file while others are the previous one noted with prev_id. I want a query to list the previous files of file3. Like wise another newly uploaded file is file6  . So when

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0e88c0/1

Expected Output

---

List of previous files of file3

```
Id |  filename 
------------
1  |  file1    
2  |  file2
```

List of previous files of file6

```
Id |  filename 
------------
4  |  file4    
5  |  file5
```

Answer (score 1):

based on the (original) sample  you provide

```
id  fname   prev_id
1   file1   (null)
2   file2   1
3   file3   2
4   file4   (null)
```

You could use a self join  eg:

```
select a.* 
from test_table a
inner join test_table b on b.fname ='file3' 
    and a.prev_id  <= b.prev_id
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9ec606/21

the a table retunn the prev_id for file3 and the b table return the valud that satisfied  your condition for query

Comment: When using the above query , i got following response                            Id |  filename 
------------
1  |  file2    
2  |  file3

Comment: change  the question after an answer  is not fair  ..  .. if you have change idea  .. you should post a new question don't invalidate  the answer provided ..

Comment: I didnt change the idea of question . i just add two more rows in the table to check the query will satisfied or not

Answer (score 1):

This will provide you result including `file3`

```
select t1.id, t1.fname, @pv := t1.prev_id prev_id
from (select * from test_table order by id desc) t1
join (select @pv := 3) tmp  // 3 is the id of file3
where t1.id = @pv;
```

Ref : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24901882/8317643

**UPDATE**

Result without `file3`

```
select (@pv := t1.prev_id) id, t1.fname
from (select * from test_table order by id desc) t1
join (
     select @pv := (
            select t4.prev_id
            from test_table t4
            where t4.id = 3
          )
) tmp
where t1.id = @pv;
```

Comment: Please  give the query if i want to exclude file3

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from file where id < 14 ;
```

First way it will list all the files which have id less than `file3` as you said they are already sorted.

Other way to do the same thing is : ( if the file uploaded has many previous records you can limit them)

```
select * from file where id in (
            select id from file where id < 14
     ) order by id DESC limit 1;
```

Comment: Note joins are always better to use than sub-query.