# A SELECT tree in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

My application is extremely slow when I move the logic for this to my scripting language. I'm hoping there's a way to leverage MySQL itself for this.

Consider the following table

```
ID' col1 ' ' col2'
-----------------
1 '   1  ' '  2  '
-----------------
2 '   2  ' '  3  '
-----------------
3 '   3  ' '  4  '
-----------------
4 '   5  ' '  4  '
-----------------
```

Is there a way to select all records where col1 is 1 or whether col1 is the col2 of a row from a previous match?

For example, if I say I need all records related to 1, I'm looking to get rows 1, 2 and 3.

Here's a query example but it only goes to the first level of depth.

```
SELECT col2 FROM table WHERE (col1 = 1) OR (col1 IN (SELECT col2 FROM table WHERE (col1 = 1)))
```

Comment: Did you try any query yet ?

Comment: have you tried using `JOIN` and `WHERE IN `?

Comment: I have used them both separately but not together. Could you give me an example?

Comment: What data structure do you actually have in there that you are trying to recursively query?

Comment: Just foreign keys to other tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a stored procedure which loops through your tree until no more children will be found. See [Recursive mysql select?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14658378/recursive-mysql-select) for how to do this!

In other DBMS you could use `WITH RECURSIVE`, which is not supported by MySQL, though. Read more about a MySQL-emulation of that here:
http://guilhembichot.blogspot.de/2013/11/with-recursive-and-mysql.html
Basically it is the same thing as before, but with a little more explanation behind it.

There might also be other ways to store your data in the first place to avoid such looping queries:
[What is the most efficient/elegant way to parse a flat table into a tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree/)

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that but if there's no other choice, I will have to do it.

Comment: It depends on whether your depth is limited or not. If so, you could just build one query with multiple joins.
Some more disuccion on the topic: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46127/recursive-self-joins

Comment: Unfortunately, the depth is not limited.

Comment: Well in that case, you have to either change your DBMS, change your table structure or use a looping stored procedure, just as pointed out above. I don't see anything else!

Comment: I ended up using a few business rules and a stored function to achieve this. Thanks for the great links!

Answer (score 0):

@a23 The solutions specified above point to a much more robust case handling.

Here is a query which would help in this case.

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE col1=1
UNION ALL
SELECT a.* FROM test a, test b WHERE a.col2=b.col1 AND a.col1!=1;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This query got me further than any other. Thanks!

Comment: This query gives you all kind of trees within the table, not just the one starting at `col1=1`.
The last element of the tree is not displayed as well, this can be fixed by changing the where clause to `WHERE a.col1=b.col2`.
I would still like to know how to go on from here? How do you want to reduce the output to one tree only?

Comment: @wolfgangwalther Are you even sure to have run this query before posting this, because it works well on my mysql?

Comment: I did run that query. But I added a lot more data to the table as well, including totally independent trees, that are not related to the tree starting at 1 at all. This query returns those as well.

Comment: So, for example, add 7/8 8/9 and 9/10 to your database. You will see, that with your query, those rows will also be returned. If I use the query in the exact same way, that you have written it, you will also see, that 3/4 and 9/10 will not be in the output, that means the last element of the tree is missing.